# run function when post is deleted in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, post

Is it possible to run a function every time a post is deleted. The function has to be run when the post is deleted from the admin or by the wp_delete_post() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

```
 add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function() { 
   //delete some stuff
   global $post;
   print_r ( $post );
 }
```

Put that in functions.php of your theme and you're set.

Read that link for any special circumstances you might need to account for

Comment: +1 - and do make sure you read the notes in the codex. They are pretty important! You may also want to check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com which is better at WP API questions.

Comment: I was wondering how i could get the post id of the post being deleted. additionally, would this still work if multiple posts are deleted?

Comment: I just edited my original post... I don't know if the code will work properly.  I was getting a headers already sent error.  Try it and let me know if it works for you.